# How to write a table content to an xml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Can somebody tell me how can i write a clientside table control content to an xml on a button click . I'm using a clientside table "selectedTexts" and on save button click i need to save the table content to an xml. Please help.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function(event) {


    var xml = "<schedule>";
    $("#selectedColumns").find("tr").each(function() {
      xml += "<data>";
      xml += $(this).find("td").eq(1).html() + "\n";
      xml += "</data>";
    });
    xml += "</schedule>";
    this.isPrototypeOf(
    alert(xml);

  })
});
```

I managed to get the string in an xml format. How can i pass this string to my codebehind so that i can write it to an xml file. Or is it any other methods available to write it from the clientside itself?

Comment: If you are able to use jQuery, a similar question has been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646205/jquery-convert-html-table-to-xml

Comment: Hi there! Please try to show some code if you can. This will make it easier for others to assist you with your question.

Comment: @Banx Please refer the updated query.

Answer (score 1):

if your table's code is as follows:

```
<table id="root">
 <tr id="category_1">
  <td>value-1</td>
  <td>value-2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="category_2">
  <td>value-7</td>
  <td>value-8</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

then following JQuery will convert it to a xml where comments wih // denote first time output:

```
var xml="";

$("#root").each( function(index){
 xml +="<"+$(this).attr("id")+">"; 
 // <root>

 $("#root tr").each( function(index){
 xml +="<"+$(this).attr("id")+">"; 
 // <root><category_1>

  $(td,this).each( function(index){
  xml +="<"+$(this).html()+">"; 
  // <root><category_1><value_1><value_2>
  }
 }
}
```

Should work :-) ta-da...

Comment: $("#selectedTexts tr").each(function(index) {
          xml += "<" + $(this).attr("id") + ">";
          alert(xml);

This still gives me the root tag.

Comment: @NewBie: $("#selectedTexts tr") clearly says find an element with selectedTexts as id then find any <tr> tag which is child of the element. So I do not understand why you get attribute of <table> tag...My apology, could not help you with such a bizarre error.

Comment: the rows are generated dynamically. How can i get the id of each rows. Right now im getting blank tabs.

Comment: The problem is with the dynamic table rows generated. Im naming it but it is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

@NewBie: I assume you are unable to generate id for `<tr>` so I am suggesting this way:

As you see in the code I have written: `$("#root tr").each( function(index){`

Here, index is the loop variable to represent current node/count of the matched element. For example if you had 50 `<tr>` row then index starts with 1 and goes upto 50. Thus you can use this variable to mark your `<tr>` tag :-)

Just edit like this:

```
$("#root tr").each( function(index){
 xml +="<"+index+">"; // replaced $(this).attr("id") with index
 // other codes here
}
```

Best of luck...